# Is there a way to communicate ROS with a controller IRC-5?

Tags: ros, rviz, urdf, ros-industrial, abb

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm working currently with ROS-I, RVIZ and a industrial from ABB, the IRB-140. I have read that you can controller it using the robot ABB's Package from ROS-industrial and ROBOTSTUDIO in a WIndows PC; however, I'm asking me if you can controllet it directly from ROS without use ROBOTSTUDIO.

Thanks for your answers.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217896/is-there-a-way-to-communicate-ros-with-a-controller-irc-5?/) by [jaam002](https://answers.ros.org/users/23513/jaam002/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2015-09-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-09-19**:
Could you point me (link) to where you read that you would need RobotStudio to use the ABB packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I have read that you can controller it using the robot ABB's Package from ROS-industrial and ROBOTSTUDIO in a WIndows PC [..]

There is no need for RobotStudio whatsoever to use the ROS-Industrial ABB packages, unless you want to control simulated hardware (ie: robots).

The `abb_driver` and other packages are designed to be used with ABB controllers, whether simulated or real.

> [..] I'm asking me if you can controllet it directly from ROS without use ROBOTSTUDIO

So: yes.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jaam002](https://answers.ros.org/users/23513/jaam002/) on 2015-09-19**:
@gvdhoorn Aaa ok, so you are able to send paths or trajectories(i.e Moveit) from rviz. Sorry, i'm new in ROS and i can't get all this concepts yet.

It is the link I was following,

http://wiki.ros.org/abb/Tutorials

and currently i'm creating the urdf for this robot.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-09-19**:
The tutorials you linked just show you that it is *possible* to run the `abb_driver` on a controller simulated in RobotStudio, nowhere is it stated that you *need* it?

And yes: install the rapid code on the ctrlr, start the `abb_driver` nodes and use the `FollowJointTrajectoryAction` server.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-09-19**:
See [How do we transmit trajectories to our ABB IRB 140 using the ABB Package](http://answers.ros.org/question/199400/how-do-we-transmit-trajectories-to-our-abb-irb-140-using-the-abb-package/) for some info on how to add support for new robot models / variants.

**Comment by [jaam002](https://answers.ros.org/users/23513/jaam002/) on 2015-09-19**:
thanks so much, i hope in the next two weeks have an advance on it.